# C++ VsCode Debugger Extra Information Showing

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++17, task, vscode-debugger, launch

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCtnv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFwW0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtxnp.png)

For simple program At time of debugging String values for all its memory location and unnecessary information is showing
How can I remove those and only show useful like s:{Hello World}

I am just expecting string s to show its value not its memory location

Comment: Use an IDE that is not utterly broken and useless (i.e. not VSCode).

Comment: I _think_ this is a GDB setting and not a VS Code one. might want to use `setupCommands` property of launch config and find the GDB command to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try `#include <string>` instead of `<bits/stdc++.h>`. In my vscode everything seems fine.

[image]

Comment: No its nothing to do with header files,Though I tried but still no improvement

it has some issue with debugging configuration or compilor.In my previous version it was working fine but after I reinstalled my Operating system I couldnot firgure it out